# Include curl commands in a PostgreSQL Docker environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, databases, images, postgresql

Using `COPY table FROM PROGRAM 'curl "www.example.com/data.csv"';` I am able to copy a CSV directly from the web into a psql table.

However, when I am running the same command from inside a docker container I get the following error:

```
COPY sites FROM PROGRAM 'curl "www.example.com/data.csv"'; 
ERROR:  program "curl "www.example.com/data.csv"" failed
DETAIL:  command not found
```

Obviously curl is not available in the containerized environment. Therefore I changed my Postgres Docker image from `image: postgres:12-alpine` to `image: postgres-12`. Unfortunately I still get the same error.

How can include the `curl` command in a containerized PostgreSQL Docker environment?

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./services/web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 manage:app
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/project/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/project/media
    expose:
      - 5000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./services/nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/project/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/project/media
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web
Include curl commands in a PostgreSQL Docker environment
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to use curl inside the container will be to use a custom Dockerfile to build you postgrsql container.
Just use the `image: postgres:12-alpine` as the base image of your Dockerfile and install curl in alpine with the following command : `RUN apk --no-cache add curl`